# Create PS script to find files

Tags: powershell

I want to start by saying coding is a bit outside of my skill set but because a certain problem keeps appearing at work, I'm trying to automate a solution.
I use the below script to read an input file for a list of name, search the C:\ for those files, then write the path to an output file if any are found.

```
foreach($line in Get-Content C:\temp\InPutfile.txt) {
if($line -match $regex){
   gci -Path "C:\" -recurse -Filter $line -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |   
Out-File -Append c:\temp\ResultsFindFile.txt 
  }
}
```

I would like to make two modifications to this.  First, to search all drives connected to the computer not just `C:\`. Next, be able to delete any found files.  I'm using the `Remove-Item -confirm` command but so far can't make it delete the file it just found.